# How to store Connection Strings in a central location for Microservices

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, microservices

I've a solution with 8 microservices.
But we are using same databases across the 8 microservices. They all are designed with single responsibility in mind.

> So far I tried 3 approaches.

**APPROACH: 1**

Setting connection strings in individual project's `appsettings.json` file and accessing it using IConfiguration (DI). But now if there is a change I need to manually change all 8 appsettings.json file

**APPROACH: 2**

Created a shared class library with `const string` connection strings in it and referencing it in all 8 projects. This seems good for me but during each deployment we had to recompile.

**APPROACH: 3**

Created a single JSON file on a central shared location and used a JSON parser to read every time I need to connect to database. This looks flexible for me at the cost of performance.

Is there any better alternative to define & use connection string across the 8 microservices without compromising flexibility and performance or with least impact?

Comment: If you plan to deploy the services separately, they should have separate configurations.  If you deploy them all together they can share a single configuration.

Comment: Also consider using a separate service for managing secrets. Check out Hashicorp Vault. It can be integrated to IConfiguration. Or you could write your own configuration/secret API and connect it to IConfiguration by implementing an `IConfigurationProvider`.

Comment: Another solution is to write a deployment tool to automate approach 1, only usable by admins of course. This keeps things simple and this tool could be expanded for other deployment tasks as well.

Comment: Azure has Key Vault for exactly this scenario, other cloud providers have the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the individual Microservices today connect to the same DB, does not mean that they will in the future, and this should be managed via configuration of the ConnectionString.

Therefore approach 2 is out.

Approach 1 is fine.  Yes you have to change it 8 times, but how often will this change?  And if you do start using different DBs then it might only be once.

Approach 3:
Here I would suggest that you don't do this yourself, but instead use more standard approach via K8s/Helm charts.

You can do this via Secrets stored on a volume.  Or perhaps better, is via Helm Charts Values.yaml files.

This article is a little dated (so syntax might have changed) but gives a good idea of how to do some of these.

https://pascalnaber.wordpress.com/2017/11/29/handling-settings-and-environment-variables-of-your-net-core-2-application-hosted-in-a-docker-container-during-development-and-on-kubernetes-helm-to-the-resque/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your target stack, where you are deploying it. But it will be somewhat of a variant of your approach 3.

a) If you are deploying on all microservices into same set of VMs, then you can create a shared settings file. Have a common config builder process that will read from your appsettings.json, appsettings.{env}.json and then your new shared settings, followed by environment variables. You can control the order of loading of the shared settings i.e. whether you want them to load before appsettings or after it.

b) If you are deploying on K8s, have it as a secret and then load it into environment variable. If you have other shared settings, you can use configmap and then load into environment variables.

In both of these options, this common connection string will be available to you via IConfiguration object itself. So individual microservices do not need to read them differently.

We follow similar setup today as we have shared settings and connection strings that is common across 10 APIs. The shared settings itself, on VM, we deploy it separately. So regular changes to microservices itself will not need deployment of the shared settings.

Also, lets say, later on your database required for microservices changes. You can always override the shared settings with your appsettings.json or appsettings.{env}.json or custom config map. That is why I mentioned, you can control the order of loading of the settings. In our case, shared settings is always loaded first during config build.